# facebook create_event posts on my app's wall not the user's wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i'm attempting to provide a facility on my site that allows a user to create a facebook event for their booking.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

now im doing the correct process:

1) first getting authorisation from the user
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://urlimredirectingto.comtype=web_server

2) requesting for an access token with the "code" that is returned in step 1
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token

3) using the access_token to create the event ...

```
   string facebookCreateUri = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/events", loggedInMember.FacebookUID);

  var formData = new HttpUrlEncodedForm() 
  {
   {"access_token", accessToken},
   {"owner", loggedInMember.FacebookUID},
   {"description", "nice event that should be on the owners wall"},
   {"name", "event on the users wall"},
   {"start_time", "1272718027"},
   {"end_time", "1272718027"},
   {"location", "rochester"},
   {"privacy","OPEN"}       
  };

  HttpContent content = HttpContent.Create(formData);
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  var response = client.Post(facebookCreateUri, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", content);
```

but the event is posted on my app's wall, not the user's wall. It shouldn't have anything to do with the authentication/access_token elements because i use the same process to post on the user's wall. (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/) and that works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came back with a solution, after a week of working at many features with Facebook SDK, it finally works!

```
protected void onPostEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CanvasAuthorizer.Authorize())
        {
            var fb = new FacebookWebClient(CanvasAuthorizer.FacebookWebRequest);

            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.description = txtEvDett.Text;
            parameters.name = txtEvName.Text;
            parameters.start_time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            parameters.end_time = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            parameters.access_token = CanvasAuthorizer.FacebookWebRequest.AccessToken;

            dynamic eventDet = fb.Post("me/events", parameters);

            litEvent.Text = String.Format("You have created the event with ID: {0}", eventDet.id);
            lnkEvent.Visible = true;
            lnkEvent.NavigateUrl = String.Format("http://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid={0}", eventDet.id);
        }
    }
```

For events, you have to request the **create_event** permission.

You should use **/me/events** to post on your events.

I user the C# SDK for Facebook from Codeplex - last version available for dld (aug 2011 - v5.2.1).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don;t see in your request for Authorization any permission.. base permissions are not enough to do the postings.
i used:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=MY_APP_ID&next=MY_APP_URL&display=page&response_type=code&canvas=1&perms=publish_stream,user_about_me,email
```

This is in the context of a canvas app. where MY_APP_URL is the url from facebook of the app: 
**http://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP_NAME_OR_ID**

See extended permissions for events and check event's page in [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/560)

---

[EDIT] - I came back, sorry, now i did a test, and indeed, it works for me, but only of i post on my app's wall; even if i provided the 'user_events' permission i get this error:

**The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden** when posting on a user's wall.
This being said, i also subscribe to this question.